# Matrix Coefficients Map a Coalgebra Morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, coalgebras

Simple question: let $C$ be a coalgebra over a field $k$.  Given a finite-dimensional right $C$-comodule $V$ determined by the structure morphism
$$a:V\to V\otimes C,$$ we have a natural 'matrix coefficients' morphism given by
$$V^*\otimes V\xrightarrow{1\otimes a}V^*\otimes V\otimes C\xrightarrow{ev\otimes 1}C.$$
Now $V^*\otimes V=End(V)^*$ has the natural structure of a coalgebra as the dual of the algebra $End(V)$, so we can ask if this morphism is one of coalgebras.  And that is precisely my question!  I would appreciate an answer and/or reference.  Thanks :)

Comment: Dually, you could ask the same question of a left module over an algebra, using coevaluation rather than evaluation. It seems to me that the resulting map $A \to \operatorname{End}(V)$ takes an element $a$ to the endomorphism it induces on $V$ via the module structure. This is a map of algebras if and only if $V$ is indeed a module. Do you think the same should be true in the co-setting?

Comment: Okay okay I'll write everything down carefully and check it.  Thanks